# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - when executing a function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I have create a UDT

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE user_tmp IS Object 
                      (id VARCHAR2(50), name VARCHAR2(100),section VARCHAR2(100));
create or REPLACE type tmp_array is table of user_tmp;
```

After this, I have created a function to display `temp` table data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMP_BY_JOB
RETURN tmp_array pipelined
IS

  v_query varchar2(4000);
  v_cursor COMMON.rCursor;
  stuDetailsTable tmp_array;
BEGIN
 v_query :=  'select * from temp';
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('QUERY: ' || v_query);
 OPEN v_cursor FOR v_query;
 LOOP
  FETCH v_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO stuDetailsTable LIMIT 100;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor fetch');
  EXIT WHEN stuDetailsTable.COUNT = 0;
    FOR i in stuDetailsTable.FIRST..stuDetailsTable.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('rows'|| i);
        PIPE row(stuDetailsTable(i));
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

CLOSE v_cursor;

RETURN; 
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('QUERY: ' || v_query);
    raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM||' -QUERY- '||v_query);
    RETURN;
END EMP_BY_JOB;
```

Now I run the following command just to test my function `EMP_BY_JOB`

```
select * from table(EMP_BY_JOB) ;
```

However, I am getting inconsistent datatype error. please help

Comment: Try to make id in ur table is  number because you are fetching the cursor and assiging i values

Comment: Would you mind including the full text of your output message? It might tell us where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your query selects a normal projection:

```
 select * from temp_table;
```

Which is fine except you are trying to populate an object table. To make this work you need to return the data from `temp_table` cast to your type.

I don't know the projection of your base table so I'm going to guess the column names match the type's attributes.  But whatever, you need something like this:

```
select user_tmp(tt.id, tt.name, tt.section) from temp_table tt;
```

Incidentally why is that a string? Your procedure has no need for dynamic SQL. This would work just as well.

```
 OPEN v_cursor FOR select user_tmp(tt.id, tt.name, tt.section) from temp_table tt;
```